# Isn't the valence band actually at a lower energy level than the conduction band?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I am currently studying *Diode Lasers and Photonic Integrated Circuits*, second edition, by Coldren, Corzine, and Mashanovitch. In chapter **1.2 ENERGY LEVELS AND BANDS IN SOLIDS**, the authors say the following:

> On the other hand, in a covalently bonded solid like the semiconductor materials we use to make diode lasers, the uppermost energy levels of individual constituent atoms each broaden into bands of levels as the bonds are formed to make the solid. This phenomenon is illustrated in Fig. 1.4. The reason for the splitting can be realized most easily by first considering a single covalent bond. When two atoms are in close proximity, the outer valence electron of one atom can arrange itself into a low-energy *bonding* (symmetric) charge distribution concentrated between the two nuclei, or into a high-energy *antibonding* (antisymmetric) distribution devoid of charge between the two nuclei. In other words, the isolated energy level of the electron is now split into two levels due to the two ways the electron can arrange itself around the two atoms.$^1$ In a covalent bond, the electrons of the two atoms both occupy the lower energy bonding level (provided they have opposite spin), whereas the higher energy antibonding level remains empty.
> $^1$The energy level splitting is often incorrectly attributed to the Pauli exclusion principle, which forbids electrons from occupying the same energy state (and thus forces the split, as the argument goes). In actuality, the splitting is a fundamental phenomenon associated with solutions to the wave equation involving two coupled systems and applies equally to probability, electromagnetic, or any other kind of waves. It has nothing to do with the Pauli exclusion principle.
> [image]
> If another atom is brought in line with the first two, a new charge distribution becomes possible that is neither completely bonding nor antibonding. Hence, a third energy level is formed between the two extremes. When $N$ atoms are covalently bonded into a linear chain, $N$ energy levels distributed between the lowest-energy bonding state and the highest-energy antibonding state appear, forming a band of energies. In our linear chain of atoms, spin degeneracy allows all $N$ electrons to fall into the lower half of the energy band, leaving the upper half of the band empty. However in a three-dimensional crystal, the number of energy levels is more generally equated with the number of unit cells, not the number of atoms. In typical semiconductor crystals, there are two atoms per primitive unit cell. Thus, the first atom fills the lower half of the energy band (as with the linear chain), whereas the second atom fills the upper half, such that the energy band is entirely full.
> The semiconductor valence band is formed by the multiple splitting of the highest occupied atomic energy level of the constituent atoms. In semiconductors, the valence band is by definition entirely filled with no external excitation at $T = 0 \ \text{K}$. Likewise, the next higher-lying atomic level splits apart into the conduction band, which is entirely empty in semiconductors without any excitation. When thermal or other energy is added to the system, electrons in the valence band may be excited into the conduction band analogous to how electrons in isolated atoms can be excited to the next higher energy level of the atom. In the solid then, this excitation creates holes (missing electrons) in the valence band as well as electrons in the conduction band, and both can contribute to conduction.

My question relates to the following section:

> The semiconductor valence band is formed by the multiple splitting of the highest occupied atomic energy level of the constituent atoms. In semiconductors, the valence band is by definition entirely filled with no external excitation at $T = 0 \ \text{K}$. Likewise, the next higher-lying atomic level splits apart into the conduction band, which is entirely empty in semiconductors without any excitation. When thermal or other energy is added to the system, electrons in the valence band may be excited into the conduction band analogous to how electrons in isolated atoms can be excited to the next higher energy level of the atom. In the solid then, this excitation creates holes (missing electrons) in the valence band as well as electrons in the conduction band, and both can contribute to conduction.

It says that "the semiconductor valence band is formed by the multiple splitting of the highest occupied atomic energy level of the constituent atoms", and then it says that "the next higher-lying atomic level splits apart into the conduction band". But isn't the valence band actually at a *lower* energy level than the conduction band?

[image]

*(From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands#Electrical_conductivity)*

What the authors seem to suggest here is that the valence band is at the highest energy level, and then the conduction band is below it ("the next higher-lying atomic level"). Or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Yes, the valence band is lower and that is what the sentence in question says.

Comment: @JonCuster How so? The sentence says that the semiconductor valence band is formed by the multiple splitting of the **highest** occupied atomic energy level of the constituent atoms, but, since energy is plotted on the $y$-axis of the image, the image shows that the conduction band is at a higher energy level than the valence band, so do these facts not go against each other?

Comment: The valence is the highest occupied atomic energy levels. The conduction band is the next set of _unoccupied_ levels. Of course, in real solid state physics the concept of directly linking atomic to crystal energy levels goes right out the window, but...

Comment: @JonCuster Ok, I see what you're saying. In that case, I think it is just worded very poorly. And I understand your point regarding the "real solid state physics"; I have purchased Sze's new 4th edition and am working my way through it to get a 'proper' understanding. Even so, I want to try to understand these authors' ('hand-wavy') explanation as I work my way through this textbook. Thanks again for the clarification!

Comment: You might want to skim through Ashcroft and Mermin if you have some spare time. It is not semiconductor focused, but it is, to me, the classic solid state physics book. It and my old Sze still get used a lot some 40 years later.